# Update a module value or re-register a filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to have a filter that depends on a lazy-loaded value?

In my case, a language pack is loaded asynchronously and the filter should reflect the loaded values once values are loaded.

```js
// setup the i18n filter
app.filter('i18n', ['localizedTexts', function(localizedTexts) {
  return function(localeKey) {
    console.log(localeKey, localizedTexts) // prints out nulls for the second argument

    return localizedTexts && localizedTexts[localeKey];
  };
}]);

// setup the defualt value
app.value('localizedTexts', null);

// load values
app.run(['$http', function($http) {
  $http.get('values.json').success(function(response) {

    // update the value -- DOES NOT INVALIDATE THE FILTER NOR THE VIEW
    app.value('localizedTexts', response);
  });
}]);
```

I've also prepared a Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/THTD3UiYgegusCl54Qhp?p=preview

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a factory instead of using a value.
[Associated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3BrseTivctbT1crS9iwi?p=preview)

```
app.factory('localizedTexts', ['$http', function($http) {
  var localizedTexts = {};

  $http.get('values.json').success(function(res) {
    angular.extend(localizedTexts, res);
  })

  return localizedTexts;
}]);
```

UPDATE: if this seemed a bit dirty then you can alternatively use the `$provide` Provider during the configuration phase and use a `decorator` to change value of the `localizedTexts` value. Check this updated [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBb01Bn97EtgATgNMLPk?p=preview)

```
app.value('localizedTexts', null);

app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('localizedTexts', ['$delegate', '$http', function($delegate, $http) {
    var localizedTexts = {};

    $http.get('values.json').success(function(values) {
      angular.extend(localizedTexts, values);
    })

    return localizedTexts;
  }]);
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to do the trick, even though it does feel a bit dirty. :)

Comment: if it feels a bit dirty, you can use the `decorator()` method of the `$provide` provider during the configuration phase and change the value itself.

Comment: What if we initialize the value with `{}`, completely dump the local variable and use the `$delegate` instead? Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ITZdaoFRBDKvL5xTwsM8?p=preview